# how to change in CI

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

How to change in CI

```
$sql1= "SELECT kwsn,SUM(jumlah) as jumlah, count(DISTINCT y.noid) as noid from  
       (select DISTINCT (a.noid_new) AS noid, a.kwsn FROM tagihandonatur a where Bulan=".$bulan." and kodej='".$_POST['id_usr']."') z 
       left join (SELECT noid,SUM(jumlah) as jumlah FROM report_tagih WHERE ((tanggal>= '".$tgl."' and tanggal<= '".$tgl2."') OR tanggal like '".$tgl."%' ) and kodej='".$_POST['id_usr']."' 
       group by noid) y on y.noid= z.noid  
       group by z.kwsn order by z.kwsn";
$rs= $dtaccess->Execute($sql1);
$dataTotal=$dtaccess->FetchAll($rs);
```

Answer (score 0):

**In CI:**

```
$sql1="SELECT kwsn,SUM(jumlah) as jumlah ,count(DISTINCT y.noid) as noid from  (select DISTINCT (a.noid_new) AS noid, a.kwsn FROM tagihandonatur a where Bulan=".$bulan." and kodej='".$_POST['id_usr']."') z left join (SELECT noid,SUM(jumlah) as jumlah FROM report_tagih WHERE ((tanggal>= '".$tgl."' and tanggal<= '".$tgl2."') OR tanggal like '".$tgl."%' ) and kodej='".$_POST['id_usr']."' group by noid) y on y.noid= z.noid  group by z.kwsn order by z.kwsn";

$data = $this->db->query($sql1);
if($data->num_rows() > 0) {
    $d = $q->result_array();
    return $d;
} else {
    return array();
}
```